# OVER function and first_value

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table named ARTICLE with many columns, specifically MFC and ANA. I want, for each MFC, the first ANA which is not null.

So, I've written this query:

```sql
select mfc, first_value(ana) over(partition by mfc) as FirstAna
from article
where ana is not null
```

But it returns many rows for each MFC.
What is the solution?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that you don't care *which* value to return (no `ORDER BY` clause), why not

```
select mfc,
       max(ana)
from article
where ana is not null
group by mfc
```

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: @coutiereric . . . Your question explicitly states:  "the first ANA which is not null."  It sounds like you *do* care which value you want.  Hence, I'm baffled both by Littlefoot's answer (which says you don't care) and by the acceptance (which suggests that it is correct).  If this is really the correct answer, fix the question so it clearly matches the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First_value will still return value for every row but that value will be first value of that partition. If you want to restrict it to one value per group you have to use group by function.

Answer (score 1):

You must define what first means by using an `ORDER BY` clause and use the keyword `DISTINCT` so you don't get the same row many times for each `mfc`:

```
select distinct
       mfc, 
       first_value(ana) over (partition by mfc order by somecolumn) as FirstAna
from article 
where ana is not null
```

Change `somecolumn` with the column's name that defines the order.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently *do* care about which value.  In Oracle you can use `keep`:

```
select mfc, 
       max(ana) keep (dense_rank first order by ???) as FirstAna
from article
where ana is not null
group by mfc;
```

The `???` is for the column that specifies the ordering for "first".